# How to change "P4" paging number format in url?

Tags: pagination

In our site we have a news section, where we are showing a list of 10 news per page.

The pagination is created OK, but when I click on page number link it creates urls like `http://example.com/news/P10` we want to change it to something more readable by users and Google as `http://example.com/news/page=1`, `http://example.com/news/page=2` something like this.

We tried a few plugins but most of the plugins are out-dated and doesn't work.

Can anyone please tell us the correct way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

- [BMS URL Change](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/bms-url-change)
- [Better Pagination](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/better-pagination)

If they don't work for you, then you'll have to write your own extension, possibly using the above as reference to approach.

**Update**

You do not want to update the core - problematic for future updates. Ideally you'd need to write an extension that probably used 2 hooks [Pagination](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/global/pagination/index.html#pagination_create) and [session](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/global/session/index.html#sessions-end). Session to interpret the custom paginated element and the Pagination hook to output the formatted pagination segment you want. You might need the [channel hook to query result](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/module/channel/index.html#channel-entries-query-result).

If you really do want to dip into the core:

- system/expressionengine/libraries/EE_Pagination.php

and/or

- system/codeigniter/system/libraries/Pagination.php

Comment: I tried oth but they didn't worked and was nto showing/doing anything. We are running latest version of EE, and those plugins looks old, so maybe why they are nto working? Any suggestion on what to modify/overwrite in core to achieve this?

Comment: Have updated answer to include the basic information.

Comment: **Please** follow @PeterLewis's advice and **do not screw with the core files**. If you are a developer (or have one hired) that is worth their salary, they can fix this with a custom extension.